# How can I prove the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^K(\frac{i}{H + i + 1})^{K-i+1} \leq \frac{K}{H}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove that for any positive integers $K$ and $H$, the following inequality is true:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^K(\frac{i}{H + i + 1})^{K-i+1} \leq \frac{K}{H}.
$$
I have tried to prove based on induction on $K$, but couldn't do the induction step. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $r = K-i+1$ we have $r \in \{1,...,K\}$, then we're to prove:

$$\sum_{r=1}^K (\frac{K-r+1}{H+K-r+2})^r \le \frac{K}{H}$$

We have $(\frac{K-r+1}{H+K-r+2} )= (1 - \frac{H+1}{H+1 + (K-r+1)}) \le (1 - \frac{H+1}{H+1+K}) = \frac{K}{K+H+1}$

So, it would be enough to prove $$ \sum_{r=1}^K (\frac{K}{K+H+1})^r \le \frac{K}{H}$$

The left is just a geometric sum, with $q = \frac{K}{K+H+1}$, then  $1-q = \frac{H+1} {K+H+1}$ and:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^K (\frac{K}{K+H+1})^r  = \frac{K}{H+1}( 1 - (\frac{K}{K+H+1})^K) \le \frac{K}{H+1} \le \frac{K}{H}$$
because $ (\frac{K}{K+H+1})^K \in (0,1) $

Comment: That's a nice proof. Thanks!